# Meteor --production not running on https://localhost:3443 but defaults to localhost:3000

Tags: meteor, https, production

I am running meteor from the console (not using mup)

Development:

```
ROOT_URL=https://localhost:3443  meteor --settings=settings.json
```

Production:

```
ROOT_URL=https://localhost:3443  meteor
--settings=settings.json
--production
```

I want production to run in https://localhost:3443 but it only shows up on localhost:3000. Both use the same settings.json file

The settings.json has this (shown below) and a couple other things:

```
"dev": {
        "ssl": {
            "key": "localhost.key",
            "crt": "localhost.crt",
            "port": 3443
        }
},
```

Comment: How are you running this - is it using mup, or are you just running `meteor` from the console?

Comment: @Mikkel I am running meteor from the console.

Comment: What happens if you set the environment variable `PORT=3443` ? Also what about Apache / Nginx? Anything like them running there , too? If so, what are their configs?

Comment: Hey @Jankapunkt, I don't think we use Apache or Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

meteor run --port 3443

Comment: Hey Thusila, http://localhsost:3443 works but https://localhost:3443 doesn't work when I try that.

Comment: you can run the project with others ports by changing the port number.I'm using above code to run several projects at same time with different ports.you don't need to manually config port

Comment: Hey Thusila, I understand that I can change the port into whichever port I would like. The issue I am running into is that I want to run using `https`. Thanks!